# Use index of matched key in mongo query

Tags: mongodb

I have to use the index of key matched in `'$in'` query of mongo and use it inside the query. I am trying to do something like this:

```
ids_arr = ['a','b','c']

ratings_arr = [1,2,3]

db.collection.insert({'id': 'b','rating': 1})

db.collection.insert({'id': 'b','rating': 3})

db.collection.find({'id': {'$in': ids_arr}, 'rating': { '$gte': ratings_arr[ids_arr.indexOf('id')]} })
```

**Expected Result**: `{'_id': ObjectId(...) ,'id': 'b','rating': 3}`

Is there a way to get the index of the matched id?

Answer (score 0):

You can do post filtering like the code below, which you can play around with on my [SaturnAPI MongoDB emulator](https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/use-index-of-matched-key-in-mongo-query).

```
// Welcome to SaturnAPI!
// You are using the MongoDB mode.
// Delete the sample code below these comments and write your own!

var collection = new Mongo.Collection(null);

var ids_arr = ['a','b','c'];

var ratings_arr = [1,2,3];

collection.insert({'id': 'b','rating': 1})

collection.insert({'id': 'b','rating': 3})

collection.find({
  'id': { '$in': ids_arr }
}).fetch().filter(function (thisItem) {
    return thisItem.rating > ratings_arr[ids_arr.indexOf(thisItem.id)];
});
```